# Cauchy Problem and stochastic representation for discontinuous initial data

Tags: pr.probability, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, stochastic-differential-equations

Where can I read more about the Cauchy problem, i.e. solutions to

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+Lu=0 \text{ and } u(0,x)=f(x)$$

for some elliptic differential operator $L$ where $f$ is not continuous?

Or about the stochastic representations in terms of a diffusion $X$,

$$ u(t,x) = E^{t,x}(f(X_T)), $$

where $f$ is not continuous?

What about the case where the set of discontinuities has measure zero?

Comment: What is $L$? $~~~~$

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? If $f$ is bounded and $L$ is nice enough then the solution can be represented via the Poisson potential as usual. In all the points of continuity of $f$ there will be limit  $u(x,t)\to f(x)$ as $t\to0+$. The proof is the same as in the case of continuous initial function.

Comment: My question is "Where can I read more about ...", so it would be great if you could give some references for learning and understanding what you just wrote :-)